# Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\Entities\AccessToken' not found in /home/u412246436/public_html/facebook/Facebook/FacebookSession.php on line 74

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to embed **Facebook login** module on my website. When I click login it goes to facebook and when it redirects back to my webpage it shows this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\Entities\AccessToken' not found in /home/u412246436/public_html/facebook/Facebook/FacebookSession.php on line 74
```

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('XXXXX','YYYYYY');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.dkclan.co/facebook/' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  // print data
  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

The AccessToken class from the Facebook packages is not included.

You've to add

```
require_once('Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
```

If you've the same error later on, just give a look at the docs or search for the missing class on https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Now I am facing this error : 

Fatal error: Interface 'Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable' not found

Comment: So you have solved the error for one missing class – and now you are not able to do the exact same thing for a different class …?

Answer (score 2):

please add neccessary php classes from Facebook SDK...

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('config.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');

require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );




use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;


FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FB_APP_ID, FB_APP_SECRET);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(FB_REDIRECT_URI);
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);
    try{
        $session->validate(FB_APP_ID, FB_APP_SECRET);
    }catch(FacebookAuthorizationException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}


if(isset($session)){
    $_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
    echo "Logged in successfully.";
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    echo "Hi ". $graph->getName();
}else{
    echo "<a href=".$helper->getLoginUrl().">Login with Facebook</a>";
}
```

You still have doubt, please refer PHP Facebook Documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

If you still have doubts, follow this link to create Facebook application. Now download source file and just replace your client ID, Client Secret and Redirect URL in config file.  That's it, it will fine.

[Facebook OAuth 2 Login using PHP with example](http://www.smarttutorials.net/facebook-oauth-2-login-using-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the required classes from the Facebook PHP SDK are included:

```
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
```